# Deserialize, JSON, WP7

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, serialization

I am trying to deserialize this Json:

```
[
    {
        "Address": "String content",
        "CategoryId": 2147483647,
        "CategoryName": "String content",
        "City": "String content",
        "Email": "String content",
        "GroupComment": "String content",
        "GroupName": "String content",
        "IntegrationType": "String content",
        "Location": {
            "Latitude": 1267432330000000,
            "Longitude": 1267432330000000
        },
        "Phone": "String content",
        "StoreComment": "String content",
        "StoreName": "String content",
        "Website": "String content",
        "ZipCode": "String content"
    }
]
  .......
```

I have 2 classes:

```
    public class Stores
    {
        public string Address { get; set; }
        .......
        public GeoLocation geoLocation { get; set; }
    }

    public class GeoLocation
    {
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
    }
```

And I am deserialize the Json like this:

```
Stores[] st = new Stores[200];
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(e.Result));
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(st.GetType());
st = serializer.ReadObject(ms) as Stores[];
ms.Close();
```

I get the Address etc, but the GeoLocation "Could not evaluate expression".

What is wrong?

Peter

Comment: First problem: That isn't JSON it's XML.

Comment: Sorry. Pasted the XML version- Ouups. The correct JSON is now in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the geoLocation member name to Location?

Comment: I changed the Classes:                                                               public class Stores
        {
            public string Address { get; set; }
            public Location Location { get; set; }

        }

        public class Location
        {
            public string Latitude { get; set; }
            public string Longitude { get; set; }
        }                                                                                                                                        Thanks!