# Parsing json with JSON.net on windows phone c#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, json.net

I'm a novice developer for WP. I have some problems with parsing json data.
I take it from the server and parse with JSON.Net.

Example of JSON  data

```
{"response":
     {"ad6a95dd8f90fad7e281994cb5a8cacd":
           {"status":"offline", "name": "Test Name",
            "id":"ad6a95dd8f90fad7e281994cb5a8cacd"}
     }
 "success":true
}
```

The first chield of "response" varies with each request to the server. 
How I can extract value of "name" field ?! Thank you in advance for your reply.

I try that in Page.xaml.cs

```
var o = JObject.Parse(result);
        var id = o["response"].First;
        ServerList.ItemsSource = id;
```

and in Page.xaml

```
<ScrollViewer Foreground="White">
                        <ListBox Margin="0,0,-12,0" Name="ServerList" Height="508" Width="415">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,20" Width="300">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </ScrollViewer>
```

I did it by example.

Comment: Are you getting any error by using this code? [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733411/deserialize-json-wp7) may help

Comment: I do not get anything in Listbox...and by using this code i'm getting  `var id ={"ad6a95dd8f90fad7e281994cb5a8cacd":
           {"status":"offline", "name": "Test Name",
            "id":"ad6a95dd8f90fad7e281994cb5a8cacd"}`  instead this `{"status":"offline", "name": "Test Name",
            "id":"ad6a95dd8f90fad7e281994cb5a8cacd"}`

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? SHow the name attribute? Using a ListBox is an overkill. Or do you want to show all the attribute values? If so, you need to to bind an IEnumerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `name` value from that Json I did this:

```
var o = JObject.Parse(result);
var id = o["response"].First.First["name"];
string name = id.Value<string>();
```

If you are actually trying to do this operation over an array of responses such as this:

```
{"responses":
    [
        {"response":
            {"ad6a95dd8f90fad7e281994cb5a8cacd":
                {"status":"offline", "name": "Test Name","id":"ad6a95dd8f90fad7e281994cb5a8cacd"} },"success":true },
        {"response":
            {"ad6a95dd8f90fad7e281994cb5a8cacd":
                {"status":"offline", "name": "Test Name2","id":"ad6a95dd8f90fad7e281994cb5a8cacd"} }, "success":true }
    ]
}
```

Then your code would need to look something like:

```
var o = JObject.Parse(result);
var ids = from c in o["responses"].Children() select c["response"].First.First;
var names = ids.Select(t => t.SelectToken("name").Value<string>());
```